# The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme' in flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

When I import `flutter_linkify/flutter_linkify.dart` package in my flutter project, I got this error in my console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on CRO U00 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

Compiler message:
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_linkify-3.1.3/lib/flutter_linkify.dart:113:44: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.merge(style),
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_linkify-3.1.3/lib/flutter_linkify.dart:117:14: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.
            .bodyText2
             ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_linkify-3.1.3/lib/flutter_linkify.dart:243:44: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.
        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText2.merge(style),
                                           ^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_linkify-3.1.3/lib/flutter_linkify.dart:247:14: Error: The getter 'bodyText2' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
 - 'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'bodyText2'.
            .bodyText2
             ^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 780

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 45s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

I am getting this kind of error when I import any package in my flutter project. I recently updated my Android studio and plugins.

Comment: What's your flutter version?

Comment: The new `TextTheme` properties require Flutter 1.13.8 or newer.  Also see https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify/issues/40.  The package should (but [doesn't](https://github.com/Cretezy/flutter_linkify/issues/44)) specify an appropriate minimum version for the Flutter SDK.

Comment: my flutter version is Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.9 @JideGuru

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `textTheme.bodyText2` is available in newer version of flutter (You're using 1.12.13+hotfix.9 which is an older version).

You have two options:

1. Use an older version of the plugin which in your case is [`flutter_linkify` 3.1.2](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_linkify/versions/3.1.2).
2. Upgrade flutter to a newer version

Comment: I upgrade flutter but now have a new problem my connected device is not shown and flutter doctor command is not work